# Random weights seem to get generated when trying to set weights in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to write code to manually set the weights in a keras network, but when I build the network, there seems to be additional weights.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> from tensorflow import keras as ke
>>> from tensorflow.keras import layers
>>> lay=layers.Dense(1,activation="relu")
>>> lay.add_weight(shape=(1,),)
<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32, numpy=array([-0.05657911], dtype=float32)>
>>> lay.set_weights(np.array([[0.5]]))
>>> lay.get_weights()
[array([0.5], dtype=float32)] # EXPEXCTD
>>> net=ke.Sequential([ke.Input(shape=(1,)),lay])
>>> net.get_weights()
[array([0.5], dtype=float32), array([[1.4100171]], dtype=float32), array([0.], dtype=float32)] # ACTUAL
>>> net.get_layer(index=0).get_weights()
[array([0.5], dtype=float32), array([[1.4100171]], dtype=float32), array([0.], dtype=float32)] # ACTUAL
```

As you can see, it created an extra 2 numpy arrays when I built the network. Why is this? What do these extra weights do? Are they the biases? Why would a network with only 2 neurons have 3 different weights? How should I set them?

### Edit:

Someone suggested building the network first, then setting the weights. This also doesn't work:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> from tensorflow import keras as ke
>>> from tensorflow.keras import layers
>>> key=layers.Dense(1,activation="sigmoid")
>>> net=ke.Sequential([ke.Input(shape=(1,)),key])
>>> key.set_weights(np.array([[0.5]]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#44>", line 1, in <module>
    key.set_weights(np.array([[0.5]]))
  File "D:\Users\Student\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 1832, in set_weights
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: You called `set_weights(weights)` on layer "dense" with a weight list of length 1, but the layer was expecting 2 weights. Provided weights: [[0.5]]...
```

It's very unclear what the shape of the array should be.

Comment: This happened because you set the weights before the actual weights of the layer were created, as you did not specify an input_shape or built the layer (by calling it with some input), which actually creates the weights inside the layer. So this is all due to this weird interference on the weights that you did.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I'm not sure I fully understand. So I suppose that I have to set the weights after creating the network, but how would I input the the weights correctly after the network is created?

Comment: just call set_weights, I don't know why you are calling add_weight for example.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy This also doesn't work. I have edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: The error is quite clear, you have two provide two sets of weights (kernel and bias), if you call get_weights and see the shapes of the returned values you will also get an idea of the correct shapes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to set the weights after creating the network, but you have to set the weights without adding them first and they must be given as a list containing a 2 dimensional numpy array and a 1 dimensional numpy array. ie:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> from tensorflow import keras as ke
>>> from tensorflow.keras import layers
>>> key=layers.Dense(1,activation="sigmoid")
>>> net=ke.Sequential([ke.Input(shape=(1,)),key])
>>> key.set_weights([np.array([[0.5]]), np.array([0.])])
>>> key.get_weights()
[array([[0.5]], dtype=float32), array([0.], dtype=float32)]
```